# How do I get a sample Spring Boot server running on my existing website?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop a web application as a side-project on my own. I'm a long-time code monkey, but I've never done much with project infrastructure, and my inexperience is showing.

I've decided to learn Spring Boot; I'm not familiar with the framework, but I've done a lot with Java, so it seemed like a decent choice. I'm following the Getting Started tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), and have created the necessary files.

I have the files on a "demo" subdirectory on my existing website, blairhippo.com. I started the application via `./mvnw -e spring-boot:run`, and all looks well; I get a bunch of info messages, including this guy:

```
2022-07-10 19:49:02.991  INFO 54726 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

So as far as I can tell, everything is running.

Except I can't actually get to the application.

According to the tutorial, the path `/greeting` should get me to my "Hello World" message. But the URLs that seem most likely (http://blairhippo.com:8080/greeting, http://blairhippo.com:8080/demo/greeting) don't actually do anything.

Is there a config file that needs some attention? What do I need to do to get this running on my server?

---

**EDIT:** Responding to Shivaji Pote below:

Thank you very much for the help. The host name is blairhippo.nfshost.com, and that DOES load a page (amusingly, one with no CSS defined). However, none of https://blairhippo.nfshost.com:8080/demo/greeting, https://blairhippo.nfshost.com:8080/greeting, or https://blairhippo.nfshost.com:8080 will return anything (and I've double-checked that the Tomcat server is running).

Both `./target/classes/application.properties` and `./src/main/resources/application.properties` exist, but are empty.

And the GreetingController.java code is boilerplate from the tutorial:

```
package com.example.servingwebcontent;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
            Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your blairhippo.com is running on different server(same machine but different application server) than sprig boot. When you run command `./mvnw -e spring-boot:run`, it launches new server(tomcat) on some port(default 8080). So your spring boot application is running independently on same machine as your blairhippo.com server. If you check the hostname of your that server and access url `http://<your-hostname>:8080/greeting`, probably it will work. If it doesn't, share your controller definition, `application.properties` and blairhippo.com hostname.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I've answered your questions in an edit above. (And, temporarily, tacked them on to your answer before realizing I'd edited the wrong thing; I've edited it back to the original state.)

Comment: @BlairHippo no problem. You said it loads a page with no css, is it from spring boot app? Also are you able to run this app locally and access /greetings endpoint? Can you also try to access this endpoint using ip once?

Comment: Sorry, the page with no CSS is the Wordpress app that BlairHippo.com normally serves-up. I have had no success getting to anything produced by the Spring Boot app. I have yet to try running the app on my local Windows machine.

Comment: Can you try to run it locally and see if it works? Also did you try using ip instead of hostname?